# can i take value of selected radio button in scriplet after clicking a button

Tags: java, javascript

I have a jsp page where i have placed several radio buttons.

After selecting radio button and clicking a submit button it will call a javascript function, which needs the selected value of the radio button to perform some operations into the scriplet.

Can anyone solve this ?

```
<td align="center"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="value1"></td>
<td align="center"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="value2"></td>
<td align="center"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="value3"></td>

<td ><a onclick="Javascript:delete();"><span>Delete</span></a></td>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function delete()
{
    <% String str= here i want that selected radio buttons value%>
}
</script>
```

Comment: JavaScript is executed at client-side, long after the JSP has been executed at server-side. If you want to do something at server-side, you need to send a new request to the server.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcBB2Fp8WNI - This is a simple video explaining the difference between client-side and server-side. He talks about PHP, but JSP technology is a server-side technology, just like PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function deleteme() {
            var values = document.getElementsByName('radio');

            for ( var i = 0, length = values.length; i < length; i++) {
                if (values[i].checked) {
                    // do whatever you want with the checked radio
                    alert(values[i].value);
                    // only one radio can be logically checked, don't check the rest
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

    <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="value1">value1</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="value2">value2</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="value3">value3</td>

    <td><a onclick="deleteme();">Delete</a></td>
```